# Mobile Device Usage

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, cross-browser, mobile-website

Where would I find usage statistics on mobile devices and browsers broken down by type over time? From a technical aspect I would like to support as many as I can in upcoming projects, however it would be beneficial to determine which devices / browsers are the pack leaders before I go supporting ancient junk.

Answer (score 3):

[StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/) has one which shows the usage of the top 9 mobile browsers.

There's also an interesting map on [iCrossing](http://connect.icrossing.co.uk/mobile-browser-market-share-map_4217) which shows usage based on country.